# Interpreting the Time Complexity for this problem

Tags: asymptotics

Say I have  a loop that runs, and after k iterations we find that it stops when:

> $\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2^k}}\right \rfloor <1$

We solve for k to find the number of iterations like so:

> $0\le\frac{n}{2^k} <1$
>
> $0\le n <2^k$
>
> $-\infty \le log_2n <k$

So is it $ k \in O(log n)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it stops exactly when this relation is satisfied, we have
$$
\log n < k \leq c' \log n
$$
for any $c'>1,$ so you have the exact order,
$$
k=\theta(\log n).
$$